# sql query with ROUND and division

Tags: mysql, sql

> Show the name and per-capita GDP for those countries with a GDP of at
>   least one trillion (1000000000000; that is 12 zeros). Round this value
>   to the nearest 1000. Show per-capita GDP for the trillion dollar
>   countries to the nearest $1000.

```
SELECT name ,
       ROUND(gdp/population,0.01)

from world
where gdp >= 1000000000000
```

this however produces bugs.

The task can be tested [here](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_WORLD_Tutorial#Trillion_dollar_economies)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument to round is the number of digits after or before the decimal.  I would start with:

```
select name ,
       ROUND(gdp/population, -3)
from world
where gdp >= 1000000000000
```

A negative number is before the decimal place.  You can read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this :

```
 SELECT NAME, ROUND(GDP/population * 0.001, 0) * 1000 as "PER-CAPITA GDP" 
         FROM WORLD WHERE GDP>= 1000000000000
```

:)
#mysql

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
SELECT name, capital FROM world WHERE length(name) = length(capital)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to explain how this will solve the problem and how selects records with gdp >=  1000000000000 when you don't check for that value.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT name, ROUND(gdp/population,-3) as "per-capita GDP" from world
WHERE GDP >= 1000000000000000000000000